# How to use Notification.deleteIntent

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent, intentservice

I'm trying to detect when my notification gets cleared. My question directly refers to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370583/android-deleteintent-how-to-use/6371297#6371297) which outlines what I'm suppose to do. This is how I'm implementing the actions:

```
// usual Notification initialization here
notification.deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, CleanUpIntent.class), 0);
notificationManager.notify(123, notification)
```

This is the CleanUpIntent class:

```
class CleanUpIntent extends IntentService {
    public CleanUpIntent() {
        super("CleanUpIntent");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        // clean up code
    }
}
```

Afterwards, I simply launch the notification like I normally would but when I go to test it out (pressing "Clear All Notifications") nothing happens. I inserted a line of code that out print something to LogCat when the IntentService gets started, but nothing ever ran. Is this how I'm suppose to use Notification.deleteIntent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is register a `BroadcastReceiver` (probably in your AndroidManifest.xml or alternatively using `registerReceiver` in a `Service`) and then set `deleteIntent` to be an `Intent` that will be caught by that receiver.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the IntentFilter flag is for catching when the notifications are cleared?

Comment: It isn't an `IntentFilter` flag, it is a `BroadcastReceiver`: see http://code.google.com/p/islamictools/source/browse/trunk/IslamicTools/src/com/alpha/commun/MsgNotification.java?spec=svn11&r=11 for an example of how you would do this.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with BroadcastReceivers, but my question was regarding how I register the receiver. Don't you need to provide it an IntentFilter whether or not you call Context.registerReceiver or manually put it in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: You do. However, if you register the receiver in AndroidManifest.xml you can use `new Intent(context, {ReceiverClassName}.class)` to send an `Intent` to the `BroadcastReceiver` without having to configure an explicit IntentFilter in the AndroidManifest.xml file. If you use `registerReceiver` then you do need to create an IntentFilter

Comment: @Femi The link on androidcompetencycenter dot com is some kind of noisy trap now. Can you replace or delete the comment?

Comment: @Femi google code disabled SVN permanently. So that link is unusable.

Answer (score 52):

sample code which will be called whenever user clears the notification, hope it will help you     .

```
 ....
 notificationBuilder.setDeleteIntent(getDeleteIntent());
 ....
  

protected PendingIntent getDeleteIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("notification_cancelled");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

NotificationBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class NotificationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action != null && action.equals("notification_cancelled"))
        {
            // your code
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifiest.xml

```
 <receiver
     android:name=".NotificationBroadcastReceiver"
     android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="notification_cancelled"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to check `action` equallity

Comment: An application could have different notifications generated with the same receiver or different actions desired depending on notification content or some other conditions.  In those cases, one might want to define an action.

Comment: Be aware that this code reusing the PendingIntent for all notifications this way. Read its description about generating unqiue ones by using different request codes or different data checked by Intent.isEqual().

Answer (score 0):

You should use getBroadcast methode instead getService and should register receiver for specific Action.

Answer (score -4):

An explicit receiver is not required. deleteIntent will be called automatically while pressing the **clear** button.